# How android bound service can differentiate between multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am developing a chat client in which I have a Service which is listening continuously from XMPP server. I have few questions regarding the architecture of this service.

1. I have read in the documentation of Service class on Android Development Page that onCreate() will be called once when the service run for the first time thats why I have written the connection to the server code in the service onCreate() method. Is it OK?
2. When I click on a ListView element which is the name of my friend in my client activity a new activity will open which will bind to the service for listening and sending chat messages.  I want to know how a service can differentiate that a specific message is for which activity? because If I am having chat with more than 1 friends there will be more than 1 activites and the service has to differentiate that which message is for which activity. I need to know how can I implement this mechanism ? It could be very helpful if there is any tutorial for this or describe what do I need to do to implement this mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract. There is nothing obviously wrong with that approach.

> I need to know how can I implement this mechanism ?

To be honest, that UI sounds... awkward. That being said, you can have the activity supply a listener or callback object to the service, which the service uses to route messages back to that activity.

Comment: if the UI sounds awkward what could be the best approach to implement the scenario I have explained ? What I am expecting from your answer is that its not good to have chat messaging in activity ? Let me know what could be the best approach to implement it ?

Comment: @Dennis: I would have a single activity. Use one fragment per chat, hosted in a `ViewPager`, so the user can just swipe horizontally to move between chats. This also will greatly simplify your interaction with the service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with fragment and ViewPager. But I will have a look into them and will try to use this approach. Let me know if you have any good link to read about it or else I will go through the documentation.

Comment: I have read about the ViewPager and Fragments. I have got some idea now which I want to share and would like to know your comments on it. I will put my login screen in activity and when the login is successfull I will open a ViewPager and a ListFragment inside the ViewPager to have friends list in it and for chat I will open a dynamic fragment by clicking the online friend from the list. But I have a question here. Is it possible to keep the communication open between fragment and service if the fragment is not active ? I mean if the fragment has been replaced with a new chat fragment?

Comment: Please suggest if you have a better idea.